# Estimating the amount of wool stuffing needed for a project

Tags: fabric, restoration, stuffing

I've just acquired a new loveseat for my apartment that's in desperate need of reupholstering. Here's the problem: the cushions are (or were) stuffed with wool. I have some experience with reupholstering furniture in the past, but I've never worked on something like this before and I can't seem to find any information that might give me an estimation on how much I'd need to re-stuff these cushions.

Is there a rule of thumb for this?

Comment: You might want to use some sponge (the kind used in mattresses) - it should be easier o work with, and you will get a more uniform distribution, with less skills.

Comment: If you can't find information online, I would find a local upholsterer and see if they would be willing to talk to you about if for a few minutes.

Comment: @virolino I may end up doing that if the wool proves too hard to work with, but for right now I'd like to try and keep it as close to original as possible as it's an antique. Not to mention I find wool so much more comfortable than sponge, if I'm honest.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'll do that when I get a chance. If this still doesn't have an answer by that point I'll post what I find out.

Comment: Are the cushions in the original condition? With the old wool inside? If yes, then weigh them, and you know how much wool you need. if it is the seats which cannot be removed for weighing, maybe you just remove the old wool, weigh it, and put it back until you can replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, from casting about online, that the use of wool stuffing for refurbishing furniture cushions is somewhat outmoded, even for a restoration project such as yours where authenticity is desired. Other than several blogs mentioning wool when discussing the pros and cons of various cushion materials, especially those which are emphasizing natural furniture materials for health and green reasons, there is not much expertise being shared online on this topic...

I did however stumble upon this most wonderful site, which just might be the ultimate source for your specific question on quantity estimate: [Home of Wool](https://homeofwool.com/shop/).  They offer wool [stuffing](https://homeofwool.com/shop/oeko-tex-certified-wool-stuffing/) and [batting](https://homeofwool.com/shop/wool-batting/), as well as [custom wool cushions and mattresses](https://homeofwool.com/category/completed-projects/), not to mention their shop bursting with cool stuff made of wool and other natural fibers.  I am certain these friendly people would very happily assist you on your quantity question.

[Foam Order](https://www.foamorder.com/pillows/pillow-stuffing.html) is another source for organic wool batting, including one manufactured with cotton backing.  (They do not offer wool stuffing, though. They do discuss how to fold wool batting for the stuffing of a pillow, however, which sounds intriguing...)

Lastly, I will just throw in this [little tutorial](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/stuff-cushions-wool-58534.html) on how to stuff a cushion with wool.

And of course as you pointed out, there are [wool battings available at Joann](https://www.joann.com/search?q=wool%20batting).

Happy reupholstering!